# how to print html table server control

Tags: html, asp.net, printing

I hit a bit of a wall, I need to print an HtmlTable that is loaded up from C# but after a bit of looking I realized that my javascript print function only works when the HtmlTable doesn't have a runat="server" unfortunately that means I can't load it up using C#... So how do I print an HtmlTable that is loaded from C#? The javascript print function is bellow. Any help is welcome.

```
function Print() {
    var prntData = document.getElementById('Table1');
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'printer', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body style="direction:rtl;"><pre>');
    mywindow.document.write(prntData.innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</pre></body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.print();
}
```